# How to display hierarchy in a single row

Tags: sql, qlikview

I´ve got table like this..

```
Name, fathers_name
-------------------
John,
Marty, John
Lucy, Marty
```

I need change it into form like this for example

```
Name, father_name, grandfather_name
-------------------------------------
John
Lucy, Marty, John
```

How is this data structure / problem called?

And how can it be transformed via Qlikview or Sql?

Thank you!

Comment: A hierarchy?  A self-referencing table?

Comment: Lucy's father is Marty

Comment: Why is marty, John not in the output?

Comment: Corrected, bad mistake...

Self-referencing table can be it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use self joins like this:

```
select a.name, b.name fathersname, c.name grandfathersname
from your_table a
left join your_table b on b.name = a.fathers_name
left join your_table c on c.name = b.fathers_name;
```

It will give you:

```
Lucy    Marty   John
Marty   John    
John
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be attempting to format hierarchical data.

See this document on the [Qlikview website](https://community.qlik.com/docs/DOC-4823). The key is to describe how the table storing the hierarchy will be built before the `LOAD` statement.

You will need to format your source data correctly in order to succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Hierarchy function works and is the best solution. Thank you!

<strike>I´ve tried to use mentioned Hierarchy but i cant make it work properly if i have got just two columns that relates to each other more than once...</strike>

I did what GurV posted. In my case, solution is:

```
ACTIVITY: 
LOAD ACTIVITY.activity_code, 
     ACTIVITY.activity_mother_code as activity_key1,
     ACTIVITY.activity_name, 
FROM
[D:\ACTIVITY.qvd]
(qvd);

left join (ACTIVITY)

LOAD ACTIVITY.activity_code as activity_key1, 
     ACTIVITY.activity_mother_code as activity_key2,
     ACTIVITY.activity_name as ACTIVITY1.activity_name, 
FROM
[D:\ACTIVITY.qvd]
(qvd);

left join (ACTIVITY)

LOAD ACTIVITY.activity_code as activity_key2, 
     ACTIVITY.activity_name as ACTIVITY2.activity_name, 
FROM
[D:\ACTIVITY.qvd]
(qvd);
```

But this is not very elegant and has to be duplicated for every level of connection. I would love to find a better way how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Father_son:
LOAD Name, 
     Father
FROM
[C:\Users\qvs1_svc_va\Desktop\New Text Document.txt]
(txt, codepage is 1252, embedded labels, delimiter is '\t', msq);

NoConcatenate

Father_GrandFather:
load Father resident Father_son;
left join 
Load Name as Father, Father as GrandFather resident Father_son;

NoConcatenate

Family:
load Name , Father Resident Father_son;
left join 
load Father , GrandFather resident Father_GrandFather;

drop tables Father_son, Father_GrandFather;